# Fibonacci sequence Proof by strong induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm a bit unsure about going about a Fibonacci sequence proof using induction. the question asks:

> The Fibonacci sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ..., which is commonly
>   described by $ F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1 \text { and } F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n−1}, ∀ \space n ∈ \mathbb{N}, n ≥ 2.$
>
> Prove by induction that the $n^{th}$ term in the sequence is
>   $$ F_n = \frac
> {(1 + \sqrt 5)^n − (1 −\sqrt 5)^n}
> {2^n\sqrt5} $$

I believe that the best way to do this would be to Show
true for the first step, assume true for all steps $ n ≤ k$ and then prove true for $n = k + 1.$

However I'm unsure how to go about this, I'd really appreciate any help or if anyone has a better way of proving this through induction.

Comment: Well you basically "just" need to show that $F_{n+2} - F_{n+1} - F_n = 0$ assuming that the formula for $F_{n+1}$ and $F_n$ is true.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350165/recursive-fibonacci-induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we rewrite

$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n−(1−\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}$$

Now we see
\begin{align}
F_n&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n-1}−(1−\phi)^{n-1}}{\sqrt5}+\frac{\phi^{n-2}−(1−\phi)^{n-2}}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n-1}−(1−\phi)^{n-1}+\phi^{n-2}−(1−\phi)^{n-2}}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n-2}(\phi+1)−(1−\phi)^{n-2}((1-\phi)+1)}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n-2}(\phi^2)−(1−\phi)^{n-2}((1-\phi)^2)}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{\phi^n−(1−\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}\\
\end{align}

Where we use $\phi^2=\phi+1$ and $(1-\phi)^2=2-\phi$. Now check the two base cases and we're done!

Turns out we don't need *all* the values below $n$ to prove it for $n$, but just $n-1$ and $n-2$ (this does mean that we need base case $n=0$ *and* $n=1$).